# bash shell how to print line in file including pattern taken from user searching with data type for pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I want to take pattern from user and print line it includes (the whole record) in the terminal its a searching process but with data types id integer (`pk`) and name string and salary integer

More explanation: If I am searching with pattern `2` and its id I have to display only the id and not salary contains 2000 and that's the problem... I didn't face this problem with string names but its in id and salary.

The code is incorrectly formatted.

```
#! /bin/bash
    #################taking tablename "database name"###############
        echo "enter table name";
        read tableName;
        if [ -f ./tables/$tableName ];
        then
    #############check table exists######################
        echo "File $tableName exists."
        echo "1)search with the id";
        echo "2)search with the name";
        echo "3)search with the salary";
        echo "enter your choice";
        read input
        echo "enter your pattern";
        read pattern;
                if [ $input -eq 1 ] 
                then 
                            test=  cut -d ',' -f1 ./tables/$tableName
                        if [[ ${#test[$pattern]} ]];
                        then
                        ###############problem here################ 
                        fi
                elif [ $input -eq 2 ]
                then 
                grep $pattern ./tables/$tableName
                elif [ $input -eq 3 ]
                then 
                ##########################problem here######################
                else 
                echo "error in input";
                fi
        else
            echo "table $tableName does not exist "
        fi
    ##########################code ends#################
```

And the file has this records:

```
id:pk,name:str,salary:int,
2,tony,2000,
3,tony,2000,
4,sara,3000,
```

Comment: What you are trying to accompish isn't clear. Do you want the user to set as input an id and then search the name in the file corresponding to that id ?

Comment: How data stored in your `tableName` file? can you post here? Also you can do same thing `salary`  and `id` using `grep` as you done in `name`.

Comment: yes i want user to set as input an id and then search the name in the file corresponding to that id

Comment: the data is written in file as shown at the end of the question

Comment: id:pk,name:str,salary:int,
    2,tony,2000,
    3,tony,2000,
    4,sara,3000

Comment: each time I search for "2" with the grep as did with sting it displays the salary and the id I want it to display the id and corresponding data only

Comment: @user2990172 So if i enter choice for `id` and enter input id as `2` then it should display result `2,tony,2000,` right?

Comment: yes thats what i mean it displays 2,tony,2000, only

Comment: Slightly OT: Instead of the `if`, `elif`, `elif` you might want to use a `case`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case to do different operations depending of the input choice. And in those cases, get the values from file.

```
echo "enter table name";
read tableName;
if [ ! -f ./tables/$tableName ]; then   #Try to avoid looooong if/then blocks if you can handle the error right away
   echo "table $tableName does not exist"
   exit 1
fi
#############check table exists######################
    echo "File $tableName exists."
    echo "1)search with the id";
    echo "2)search with the name";
    echo "3)search with the salary";
    echo "enter your choice";
    read input
    echo "enter your pattern";
    read pattern;
entries=()        #Initialize entries with an empty array
case $input in 
    1) #case by id
       entries=($(grep -P "^${pattern}," "./tables/$tableName"))
       ;;
    2) #case by name
       entries=($(grep -P "^\d*,${pattern}," "./tables/$tableName"))
       ;;
    3) #case by salary
       entries=($(grep -P ",${pattern}$" "./tables/$tableName"))
       ;;
    *) #choice not found
       echo "error in input"
esac

if [[ "${#entries[@]}" = "0" ]]; then #entries array count is 0
   echo "No entries found matching your pattern"
   exit 1
fi

#To be noted that here, entries is useless if you just want to print the match
#(use grep directly and it will print the output).   

#Thank's to Jonathan Leffler for this trick allowing to print a whole array in one line
printf "%s\n" "${entries[@]}"
```

Comment: You could replace the last loop with `printf "%s\n" "${entries[@]}"` to good effect.  Generally, use `"$@"` or `"${array[@]}"` to preserve spacing and multiple words, etc.  And the `printf` function does the repeating over the values in the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, not really used to printf in bash. Updating